# Buck converter not working

Tags: mosfet, pwm, driver, buck

I designed a buck converter on breadboard as shown in the picture. I am applying PWM from my microcontroller. I am not sure why this circuit is not working, I have spent so much time on it. Is there any problem with the connections? Or have I picked the right MOSFET and MOSFET driver? The MOSFET is N-type and the MOSFET driver is low- and high-side compatible. How do I know if the MOSFET driver is working as high-side or low-side? I guess PWM input from microcontroller is not a problem as I have tested it with a signal generator also.

[image: buck converter]

---

[MAX627 data sheet**](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX626-TSC428.pdf)

[image]

Comment: What are the input/output voltages and currents? switching frequency? Where is the feedback voltage signal? What is not actually working?

Comment: Looks to me like your inductor is too big, capacitor is too small, and you arent even using a Schottky type diode?

Comment: also looks like you were meant to do a P channel MOSFET not an N channel

Comment: @KyranF input voltage is 15V and i am getting nothing as output. The switching frequency is 100Khz. I am not using any feed back voltage signal yet. I calculated the inductor and capacitor through calculations.The diode is Schotty type.

Comment: Well i'm just telling you now, the values are wrong or you made a typo. Also, to switch the FET the gate needs 15V + at least Vgs(th) in the NFET datasheet, to turn on. Right now it's never turning on. How can you expect to control the conversion process without feedback? Buck converters require closed loop control.

Comment: Did you do the appropriate bypass caps as suggested in the datasheet? Look in the "application hints" section.

Comment: @KyranF Errm not sure whats wrong in values, which values you suggest. Ill try to use Ptype mosfet and see what i get. I have not used any feedback control yet as i am trying to get just basic buck convertor work.

Comment: I didnt understand by bypass caps..which datasheet are you talking about?

Comment: http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX626-TSC428.pdf  page 4 is the mention of bypass capacitors for the MOSFET gate driver IC.

Comment: I've made many buck converter circuits around the 50-150kHz switching frequency, and the inductor values are never more than 100 micro Henry. You have a 2.7 milli Henry inductor shown in your drawing. The output capacitance should also be much larger, for designs like this they should be upwards of 50-100uF

Comment: @KyranF oh i see, I m not sure how my calculations ended up with those values. I will have a look at them. I will try the same circuit with p-type mosfet and see where it goes.

Comment: Good luck! I do suggest you put the capacitors in for the MOSFET driver IC too, especially because it's switching at 100kHz. I don't know if it can/should be switching that fast, I didn't check the datasheet for that

Comment: You should always include a link to any relevant datasheets and an indication of what the IC does. People should not have to look these up as it wastes the same effort over many times whereas if you do it they can use the information you provide. I have added these at the bottom of the diagram | s others say THE fatal error is that an N Channel MOSFET needs positive drive voltage ABOVE source to turn on and your circuit cannot provide it. A P channel MOSFET would (tend to) work as shown with Vout ~= Vin x PWM%

Comment: @KyranF It didn't work with P-type mosfet too..It gives me the same output voltage as input when I apply PWM. Duty cycle of PWM is 50%.

Comment: @SamadMuhammad I guess your switching frequency is too high, so it never gets to drain energy out of the inductor through the catch diode. Also, you should probably put a load on the output, like a 100mA worth of LED+resistors or just resistors. Many of these converter topologies don't quite work without load, unless they are very complex (you are doing a simple open loop control right now)

Answer (score 3):

I think, that's not the right kind of MOSFET and driver.  In the present design, you've got an N-channel MOSFET and a driver [MAX627](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/power-switching/MAX627.html).  You are saying that it's "high side compatible".  But there is nothing in a datasheet that indicates that that driver is for for a high-side N-channel MOSFET.

Combinations that should work:

- Keep the driver that you currently have, but use a P-channel MOSFET.
- Keep the N-channel MOSFET, but use some high-side gate driving technique (bootstrap gate driver, perhaps).

Comment: Agreed, looks like a high-side circuit topology but using an N-FET. Need some charge-pump goodness to get above the 15V and turn that sucker on!

Comment: Yes, the MAX627 is just a low side driver. A P channel could be used with it but only because the input is 15V, much higher an driver and FET gate would be damaged.

Comment: MAX627 is high and low side driver. Its mentioned in RS components specifications when buying it.

Comment: @SamadMuhammad There is a big difference in High-side P-channel drive and High-side N-channel drive. They are both high side, but driving them is completely different.  It sounds like it's a high-p / low-n driver, not a high-n / low-n driver.

Comment: @Majenko so do you think that using ptype mosfet with same driver will work out?

Comment: @SamadMuhammad  Try to understand: how gate works in P- and N-channel, why the present setup doesn't work, why a P-channel should work.  We have provided plenty of insight.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I tried using same driver with P channel mosfet but its not working